# Response timeout or slow response from my node server hosted at Heroku's free plan

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-cloud-firestore, twilio, heroku-cli

I am running a nodejs app on Heroku free tier.
Free tier is more than enough for occasional traffic, just a few times a month for a backend admin system.

However, if a few multiple Rest API calls were made within 1 or 2 minutes, it will encounter timeout error. Actual scenario - my node server is receiving WhatsApp replies coming from Twilio - Twilio uses webhook to call the REST API from my node server hosted at Heroku free tier. Multiple WhatsApp replies of about 10 - 20 is expected but could come in within a minute. Node server receives the data from Twilio and writes to FireStore for each WhatsApp reply.

I am reading Heroku's help document on how to deal with request time-outs > https://help.heroku.com/PFSOIDTR/why-am-i-seeing-h12-request-timeouts-high-response-times-in-my-app

1. Can I increase the number of web workers under the current Free unverified account?
   I tried from the Heroku CLI and get the following response

```
 heroku ps:type worker=standard-2x
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.59.2 to 7.60.2.
 ▸    Type worker not found in process formation.
 ▸    Types: web
```

2. If I get my account verified by adding a credit card, how many web workers can I add to the existing free dyno?
3. If I stay at Free tier, without upgrading to say Hobby tier. Even if there is unexpected event of a spike in traffic, my dyno will just go to sleep once the free dyno hours are used up - Heroku will not automatically charge my credit card for the excess traffic right?  I am very concern due to news about Firebase users charged for thousands of dollars due to unexpected spike in traffic and there is no way to cap or limit it.
4. If I am expecting up to 20 simultaneous/concurrent REST API calls to my node server at Heroku within a minute - how many web workers should I increase?

Comment: On the Twilio side, their is a 10 second timeout for HTTP response. Take a look at these URL fragments, to see if that changes the behavior. Make sure to set sni=y for retries. https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-connection-overrides more details here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11205

Answer (score 0):

On a free account, you can only have one worker at a time. If you add more dynos, you will be charged.

When your free Heroku dyno sleeps because it is not being used, if it receives a new request it has to wake up. Waking up takes quite a bit of time and likely is longer than Twilio's 10 second timeout for HTTP responses. I think your app is probably failing not because of the spike of traffic especially as you are using Node which can handle multiple connections with ease, but because your sleeping dyno times out.

You might find some benefit adding the same URL as the [fallback URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security/availability-reliability#fallback-urls) for your number. That would allow Twilio to call your server, wake it up and if it fails the first time because it timed out, the fallback URL will make a second attempt which would hopefully succeed.

In reality, the best practice is to pay for an account that allows you to keep your dyno running the whole time.